# C# Access check boxes within combobox dropdown

Tags: c#, user-interface, checkbox, combobox, dropbox

So I'm currently trying to access check box items held as a collection within a combo box. My problem is, when I go to set:

var dropGenre = Drop_Genre.Items;

and change the position each run through a loop, I cant seem to access anything "check box like" at any point. I'm trying to see which items in the drop down are "checked" and return the name of those items.

I tried looking through the windows documentation but didn't have any luck finding out about check boxes within combo boxes; in fact most sources I checked were asking if it was even possible and didn't seem to reference this functionality at all. Thanks, sorry if this is poor formatting, first time asking something on here.

Comment: If you have a control that has… _”check box items held as a collection within a combo box”_ … Then, this sounds like a “custom user control.” Is this a custom user control or is the description incorrect? If it is a custom control, then it may help you to look at how it is implemented to find how to access the check box items.

Comment: I suggest you peruse the SO [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) section as it shows how SO works. The [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful.